# INSERT statement with INNER JOIN SELECT SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I try to make a query which can INSERT data quickly, before I execute query with INSERT statement I build a query which contains SELECT SUM CASE and INNER JOIN.

And my code contains error. Here's my code :

```
SELECT  pkg_guru.id_pkg ,
        pkg_guru.id_guru ,
        guru.nama_guru ,
        guru.mapel_diampu ,
        pkg_guru.id_penilai ,
        penilai.nama_penilai ,
        pkg_guru.tahun ,
        pkg_guru.sem ,
        pkg_guru.kompetensi 
        SUM(CASE WHEN pkg_guru.kompetensi = "1" THEN pkg_guru.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp1 ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pkg_guru.kompetensi = "2" THEN pkg_guru.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp2 ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pkg_guru.kompetensi = "3" THEN pkg_guru.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp3 ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pkg_guru.kompetensi = "4" THEN pkg_guru.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp4 ,
        SUM(pkg_guru.jawaban) AS total_skor
FROM    pkg_guru
        INNER JOIN guru ON pkg_guru.id_guru = guru.id_guru
        INNER JOIN penilai ON pkg_guru.id_penilai = penilai.id_penilai
GROUP BY pkg_guru.id_pkg ,
        pkg_guru.id_guru ,
        guru.nama_guru ,
        guru.mapel_diampu ,
        pkg_guru.id_penilai ,
        penilai.nama_penilai
```

Can you tell me what's wrong in this query code?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What do you use? mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a comma missing after `pg.kompetensi` and you haven't included all of the required columns in your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  pg.id_pkg ,
        pg.id_guru ,
        g.nama_guru ,
        g.mapel_diampu ,
        pg.id_penilai ,
        p.nama_penilai ,
        pg.tahun ,
        pg.sem ,
        pg.kompetensi ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pg.kompetensi = "1" THEN pg.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp1 ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pg.kompetensi = "2" THEN pg.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp2 ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pg.kompetensi = "3" THEN pg.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp3 ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pg.kompetensi = "4" THEN pg.jawaban
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS nilaikp4 ,
        SUM(pg.jawaban) AS total_skor
FROM    pkg_guru pg
        INNER JOIN guru g ON pg.id_guru = g.id_guru
        INNER JOIN penilai p ON pg.id_penilai = p.id_penilai
GROUP BY pg.id_pkg ,
        pg.id_guru ,
        g.nama_guru ,
        g.mapel_diampu ,
        pg.id_penilai ,
        p.nama_penilai ,
        pg.tahun ,
        pg.sem ,
        pg.kompetensi
```

Comment: Not only comma, 3 columns missing in `GROUP BY` as mentioned by @Gaara of Desert

Comment: ahh thanks Matt and Jesuraja... you helped me so well !! ^__^

Answer (score 0):

You missed comma after `pkg_guru.kompetensi` at the third line. And `pkg_guru.tahun,pkg_guru.sem,pkg_guru.kompetensi` in `GROUP BY` section.